Multiple Folder Image Minipulation
I have created an image tool which crops, scales, resizes. I now want to create a bulk image feature where it will take multiple folders with images inside, extract the images and then creates the a new folder with the original file name and put's the processed images back into the folders created.
I'm 95% there with creating this tool but I'm stuck on trying to process multiple folders which is where it's going wrong.
I've managed to get it so I can process one folder, extract the images, create a new folder with the original file name and put the processed image back into that folder.
I'm stuck on what to do next. I have tried searching the problem but I think my situation is a bit niche so I didn't find much. So if anyone has a solution that would be much appreciated.
My specific question is:
How can I modify my current code to correctly process multiple folders, extract the images, and place the processed images back into the respective new folders?


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const folderInput = document.getElementById('folderInput');
  folderInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    updateSelectedFilesPreview('folderInput', 'bulk_selectedFilesPreview');
    console.log('Folder input changed. Files selected:', folderInput.files.length);
  });
});

function processFolderImages() {
  const folderInput = document.getElementById('folderInput');
  const output = document.getElementById('bulk_output');
  const finalSize = 2000;
  const maxScaleSize = 1900;
  const compressionQuality = 0.5;

  const zip = new JSZip();
  const promises = [];

  const oldButton = document.querySelector('.download-bulkimg-button');
  if (oldButton) {
    output.removeChild(oldButton);
  }

  const folderMap = {};

  // Iterate through the selected files and categorize them by their folder paths
  for (let i = 0; i < folderInput.files.length; i++) {
    const file = folderInput.files[i];
    const filePath = file.webkitRelativePath || file.relativePath || file.name;
    const folderPath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));

    console.log(`Processing file: ${file.name}`);
    console.log(`File path: ${filePath}`);
    console.log(`Folder path: ${folderPath}`);

    if (!folderMap[folderPath]) {
      folderMap[folderPath] = [];
    }

    folderMap[folderPath].push(file);
  }

  console.log('Folder map:', folderMap);

  for (const folderPath in folderMap) {
    const files = folderMap[folderPath];
    const folder = zip.folder(folderPath);

    console.log(`Processing folder: ${folderPath}`);

    files.forEach(file => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      promises.push(
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            console.log(`Reading file: ${file.name}`);
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = e.target.result;
            img.onload = function() {
              console.log(`Image loaded: ${file.name}`);
              const cropCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
              const cropCtx = cropCanvas.getContext('2d');
              const {
                left,
                top,
                width,
                height
              } = getBoundingRectangle(img);

              cropCanvas.width = width;
              cropCanvas.height = height;
              cropCtx.drawImage(img, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

              const scaleCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
              const scaleCtx = scaleCanvas.getContext('2d');
              let scaleWidth, scaleHeight;
              if (width > height) {
                scaleWidth = maxScaleSize;
                scaleHeight = (height / width) * maxScaleSize;
              } else {
                scaleWidth = (width / height) * maxScaleSize;
                scaleHeight = maxScaleSize;
              }

              scaleCanvas.width = scaleWidth;
              scaleCanvas.height = scaleHeight;
              scaleCtx.drawImage(cropCanvas, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

              const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
              const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
              const canvasSize = finalSize;
              canvas.width = canvasSize;
              canvas.height = canvasSize;

              let sourceWidth, sourceHeight;
              if (scaleWidth > scaleHeight) {
                sourceWidth = canvasSize;
                sourceHeight = (scaleHeight / scaleWidth) * canvasSize;
              } else {
                sourceWidth = (scaleWidth / scaleHeight) * canvasSize;
                sourceHeight = canvasSize;
              }

              const xOffset = (canvasSize - sourceWidth) / 2;
              const yOffset = (canvasSize - sourceHeight) / 2;

              ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
              ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize);
              ctx.drawImage(scaleCanvas, 0, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, xOffset, yOffset, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);

              canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                console.log(`Image processing complete: ${file.name}`);
                compressImage(blob, compressionQuality, function(compressedBlob) {
                  folder.file(file.name, compressedBlob);
                  resolve();
                });
              }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
            };
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        })
      );
    });
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('All images processed. Generating ZIP...');
    if (!document.querySelector('.download-folder-img-button')) {
      zip.generateAsync({
        type: 'blob'
      }).then(function(content) {
        console.log('ZIP generated.');
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = 'Download';
        button.classList.add('download-bulkimg-button');
        button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = URL.createObjectURL(content);
          a.download = 'processed-images.zip';
          a.style.display = 'none';
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
        });
        output.appendChild(button);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error generating ZIP:', error);
        output.innerHTML = 'An error occurred while generating the ZIP.';
      });
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error processing images:', error);
    output.innerHTML = 'An error occurred during processing.';
  });
}

function getBoundingRectangle(img) {
  const offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const offscreenCtx = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
  offscreenCanvas.width = img.width;
  offscreenCanvas.height = img.height;
  offscreenCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  const imageData = offscreenCtx.getImageData(0, 0, offscreenCanvas.width, offscreenCanvas.height);
  const data = imageData.data;

  let left = offscreenCanvas.width;
  let top = offscreenCanvas.height;
  let right = 0;
  let bottom = 0;

  for (let y = 0; y < offscreenCanvas.height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < offscreenCanvas.width; x++) {
      const index = (y * offscreenCanvas.width + x) * 4;
      if (data[index] !== 255 || data[index + 1] !== 255 || data[index + 2] !== 255) {
        left = Math.min(left, x);
        right = Math.max(right, x);
        top = Math.min(top, y);
        bottom = Math.max(bottom, y);
      }
    }
  }

  const width = right - left;
  const height = bottom - top;

  console.log(`Bounding rectangle - left: ${left}, top: ${top}, width: ${width}, height: ${height}`);

  return {
    left,
    top,
    width,
    height
  };
}

function compressImage(blob, quality, callback) {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  img.onload = function() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    canvas.toBlob(function(compressedBlob) {
      console.log('Image compressed.');
      callback(compressedBlob);
    }, 'image/jpeg', quality);
  };
}
<div id="bulkContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="imageContent-centrecontainer" style="margin-left: 150px;">
    <p class="header-card">Bulk Image Tool</p>
    <div class="imagecontent-container">
      <div class="imageform-container">
        <form>
          <div class="custom-input-container">
            <!-- Updated input for folder selection -->
            <label for="folderInput" class="custom-button">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud-arrow-down" style="display: grid; justify-content: center;"></i>
                                Drag &amp; Drop Or Select
                            </label>
            <div id="fileList" class="file-list"></div>
            <!-- Folder input -->
            <input type="file" id="folderInput" class="custom-input" webkitdirectory multiple>
          </div>
          <button class="custom-button-process" type="button" onclick="processFolderImages()">Process Images</button>
          <div id="bulk_output"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgdisplay-container">
    <div class="imgpreview-container" id="dragAndDropArea">
      <div id="bulk_selectedFilesPreview">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




File system interactions may be a bit limited from in-browser JavaScript.  If you're looking to specify a single top-level folder and recursively read all files therein, I wouldn't be surprised if that's outside the realm of what in-browser JavaScript can do with a selected folder.  (I could be wrong of course.)

@David This was my fear! I've tried a few ways around to try and
circumvent it but nothing has worked so far, so I thought I'd ask around see if anyone knows.

You are looking for a way to read all directories and their files recursively in-browser. This is partially possible with the showDirectoryPicker() method.
Unfortunately, it is not fully supported right now because it is still an experimental feature and currently only works with some newer versions of Chrome, Edge, and Opera.
Note:

It won't work with the code preview feature due to iframe cross-origin limits.
System files are not allowed in the selected folder.
The user has to interact with the page or a UI element for this feature to work.

Here is an example:


// #select-btn  = <button>
document.getElementById('select-btn').addEventListener('click',async event => {
  console.log(1);
  try {
        const directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker()
        const files = await listAllFilesAndDirs(directoryHandle);
        console.log('files', files);
    }catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})

async function listAllFilesAndDirs(dirHandle) {
    const files = [];
    for await (let [name, handle] of dirHandle) {
        const {kind} = handle;
        if (handle.kind === 'directory') {
            files.push({name, handle, kind});
            files.push(...await listAllFilesAndDirs(handle));
        } else {
            files.push({name, handle, kind});
        }
    }
    return files;
}
<button id="select-btn">Select a folder</button>



